# How to perform countif in R and export the data?

Tags: r, export, countif

I have a set of data:

```
ID<-c(111,111,222,222,222,222,222,222)
TreatmentDate<-as.Date(c("2010-12-12","2011-12-01","2009-8-7","2010-5-7","2011-3-7","2011-8-5","2013-8-27","2016-9-3"))
Treatment<-c("AA","BB","CC","DD","AA","BB","BB","CC")
df<-data.frame(ID,TreatmentDate,Treatment)
df

ID   TreatmentDate   Treatment
111   12/12/2010     AA
111   01/12/2011     BB
222   07/08/2009     CC
222   07/05/2010     DD
222   07/03/2011     AA
222   05/08/2011     BB
222   27/08/2013     BB
222   03/09/2016     CC
```

I also have another dataframe showing the test date for each subject:

```
UID<-c(111,222)
Testdate<-as.Date(c("2012-12-31","2014-12-31"))
SubjectTestDate<-data.frame(UID,Testdate)
```

I am trying to summarise the data such that, say if I want to see how many treatment a subject has prior to their test date, I would get something like this and I would like to export this to a spreasheet.

```
ID     Prior_to_date      TreatmentAA   TreatmentBB    TreatmentCC    TreatmentDD
111       31/12/2012           1             1              0              0
222       31/12/2014           1             2              1              1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could join the two dataset with 'ID', create a column that checks the condition ('indx'), and use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 dcast(setkey(setDT(df), ID)[SubjectTestDate][,
     indx:=sum(TreatmentDate <=Testdate) , list(ID, Treatment)], 
       ID+Testdate~ paste0('Treatment', Treatment), value.var='indx', length)
#    ID   Testdate TreatmentAA TreatmentBB TreatmentCC TreatmentDD
#1: 111 2012-12-31           1           1           0           0
#2: 222 2014-12-31           1           2           2           1
```

#### Update

Based on the modified 'df', we join the 'df' with 'SubjectTestDate', create the 'indx' column as before, and also a sequence column 'Seq', grouped by 'ID' and 'Treatment', use `dcast` and then remove the duplicated 'ID' rows with `unique`

```
  unique(dcast(setkey(setDT(df), ID)[SubjectTestDate][, 
    c('indx', 'Seq') := list(sum(TreatmentDate <= Testdate), 1:.N) ,
    .(ID, Treatment)], ID+ Seq+ Testdate ~ paste0('Treatment', 
            Treatment), value.var='indx', fill=0), by='ID')
  #    ID Seq   Testdate TreatmentAA TreatmentBB TreatmentCC TreatmentDD
  #1: 111   1 2012-12-31           1           1           0           0
  #2: 222   1 2014-12-31           1           2           1           1
```

Comment: I have installed data.table but it still says "could not find function "dcast"?  Wonder if you know what the issue is?

Comment: @Headandtoes I am using the devel version of data.table.  For other versions, I think `dcast.data.table` works

Comment: Thank you so much.  Just one more question - is there an easy way to export the data to excel?

Comment: @Headandtoes There are several if you search the web for "write.xls" with "r"

Comment: Hi, I notice a possible error in the code - If I change one of the treatment dates to after the test date,(e.g. treatment date: 2016-1-31, test date: 2014-12-31)   That treatment will still be counted but it should not be counted?

Comment: @Headandtoes Could you update the example in the post and the expected output so that I can look into

Comment: Post is now updated.   for the last row in df, the treatment date is now 03/09/2016.  this treatment should not be counted as it is after the test date which is 31/12/2014.   Thank you so much for all your help!!

Comment: @Headandtoes Please check if this works `unique(dcast(setkey(setDT(df), ID)[SubjectTestDate][, c('indx', 'Seq') := list(sum(TreatmentDate <= Testdate), 1:.N) , .(ID, Treatment)], ID+ Seq+ Testdate ~ paste0('Treatment', Treatment), value.var='indx', fill=0), by='ID')`

Comment: I see this in the output "class(fill) != class(indx), coercing 'fill' to integer" but otherwise the output is correct.  Thank you so much.  I don't know if this is a bit too much to ask for but would it be possible to provide more explanation to the code?  I tried to search for the explanation but what I managed to find are rather difficult to understand.

Comment: @Headandtoes  I noticed that the warning is in the `fill`. Can you try `fill=0L`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78562/discussion-between-head-and-toes-and-akrun).